# Find file by name

Tags: python

I am coding a bot for a chatroom on chatango, I am streaming some stuff and I want to add a playlist, so the users can say "!add seinfeld.mov" or whatever and it will add it to the playlist, if the file does not exist it will tell them nope, if it finds it, it will add it to the playlist.

```
if cmd == "add":  
    if os.chdir("C:\Media") and file.name == (args):  
        print('vodka!')
    else:
        print('nope')
```

All required dependencies are imported, whenever I scan for a file that is there, it prints `nope`.

Comment: also, I don't know how to do the code block thing since its complicated here compared to any other forum :/// syntax is ok.

Comment: Please show more of your code and explain what exactly you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: I am coding a bot for a chatroom on chatango, I am streaming some stuff and I want to add a playlist, so the users can say "!add seinfeld.mov" or whatever and it will add it to the playlist, if the file does not exist it will tell them nope, if it finds it, it will add it to the playlist.

Comment: @Mzon What is `file` and what is `args`?

Answer (score 1):

You just need to see if the file is in `C:\Media` (remember to escape the slash). You can use [`os.listdir()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.listdir).

```
import os
if cmd == "add":
    if args in os.listdir("C:\\Media"):
        print("vodka!")
    else:
        print("nope")
```

Answer (score 0):

First, let's make a function to find the file, using [`os.walk`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.walk):

```
import os

def find_file(in_path, name):
    for root, directories, filenames in os.walk(in_path):
        if not filenames:
            continue

        for filename in filenames:
            if filename == name:
                return os.path.join(root, filename)

    return None
```

Then we can do:

```
if cmd == "add":  
    if find_file("C:\\Media", args) is not None:  
        print('vodka!')
    else:
        print('nope')
```

This will actually find the file recursively, under any directory in `C:\Media`, and return the path where it is.

Comment: Fixed, thanks! It works either way on my system, but escaping it is better.